# Search post by category in wordpress

Tags: php, wordpress, search, blogs

I have a sidebar with all the categories created like this in functions.php

```
// Widgets Setup 
function init_widgets($id) {
    register_sidebar(array(
        'name'  => 'Sidebar',
        'id'    => 'sidebar',
        'before_widget' => '<div>',
        'after_widget'  => '</div>',
        'before_title'  => '<h3>',
        'after_title'   => '</h3>'
    ));
}

add_action('widgets_init', 'init_widgets');
```

This is used to display all the categories from wordpress.

When I click a category I need to open a search box and search within that specific category.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: This is a code which initialize sidebar widgets. The code doesn't do what you are saying.

Comment: Yes, that's why I am asking because I don't know who to proceed further.

Comment: The easiest way would be to insert the php code responsible for your functionality inside the templat.

Comment: Yes, I am calling the sidebar inside the template, but I need to be able to click the category and open a search box and search in each category.